# MiKTex Configuration Utility and texify.exe did not succeed

Tags: miktex

I am using Windows 10, installed MiKTex 2.9 and wanted to compile my project with texworks. It is not working. I get the following errors:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

--enable-installer: unknown option

Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.
```

The texify log file says:

```
texify - running 'initexmf --enable-installer --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: My initexmf knows the option --enable-installer. Sounds as if your system is not up-to-date, check with the update manager (admin and user). Beside this: I don't use texify, it doesn't give good error messages, sometimes it gives errors when everything work. I run the tools individually.

Comment: I already did an update with Update MiKTeX. It still doesn't work. What do you use instead of texify and how do you run the tools individually? I am new to miktex.

Comment: Did you eventually get around the problem?

Comment: No. But I installed Windows 7 again. Maybe it works there.